# Member always appears offline

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I want to make a profile command that shows member status(online, offline, etc.).

```
@client.command(passContent=True)
@commands.has_role("║Участники")
async def профиль1(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.send(f'your status is {ctx.author.status}')
```

When someone uses this command he always appears offline. ("your status is offline")

Comment: see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=member%20intents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Intents!

Intents are new in version 1.5 of discord.py

- Activate Intents on the [discord developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)
- Add this to the top of your code

```py
intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '?',intents=intents)

# OR

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents=intents)
```

Then everything should work fine.

You can also join the discord.py server via [this link](https://discord.gg/dpy)